# dll.refresh with devenv vs msbuild (Website Project, not application)

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, continuous-integration

I am creating a CI server for our application(s) and have run into an issue with msbuild for our Website Project.  It builds off a solution, but no proj file (as it is not a website application and cannot be).  MSBuild won't pull in the dll.refresh files into the bin folder.  (Not specific to a CI issue, but that's the goal)   If I run it against devenv.com (CLI attempts) to build then it does pull in the dll.refresh and appears to work just fine.

From what I can find on MsBuild logs, it appears the the Copy task (which is just the default rule from msbuild itself) doesn't target the /bin folder when looking for the DLL files, but the root of the solution (/www in this case).

Just looking for some more information, as all other research points have seeming run dry at this point.  (Does it have to be Msbuild?  No, but I would like to make the CI configuration very simple for anyone else to re-produce and a custom build script/batch file and VS install on the CI server would make it much more complex).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe using VS2013 / MSBuild 12.0.31101.0.

Repro:

1. Create new website in VS
2. Add Reference to assembly on disk
3. Clean the `bin` directory of all files except `*.refresh`
4. Save all
5. Run `msbuild WebsiteSolution.sln`

Result: DLLs referenced in the `*.refresh` are re-created.

A read-through of the generated MSBuild file shows that the paths in the `*.refresh` files are resolved relative to the base directory of the website.  I will note that this only occurs on the `Build` target, so I don't know what you mean when you say "the Copy task [...] is the default rule".  Perhaps you are using some custom MSBuild target which needs to include the default target?

The relevant parts of the generated MSBuild (produced with `MSBuildEmitSolution=1`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Edit: Snipped -->
    <!-- The website location is stored relative to the .sln -->
    <!-- (which is the same as the location of the temporary msbuild file) -->
    <Project_[...]_AspNetPhysicalPath>..\..\WebSites\WebSite1\</Project_[...]_AspNetPhysicalPath>
    <!-- Edit: Snipped -->
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup />
  <!-- Edit: Snipped -->
  <Target Name="Build" Condition=" ('$(CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents)' != '') and (false or ( ('$(Configuration)' == 'Debug') and ('$(Platform)' == 'Any CPU') ) or ( ('$(Configuration)' == 'Release') and ('$(Platform)' == 'Any CPU') )) " DependsOnTargets="GetFrameworkPathAndRedistList">
    <!-- Edit: Snipped -->
    <!-- *.refresh items are discovered and saved in [...]_References_RefreshFile -->
    <CreateItem Include="$(Project_[...]_AspNetPhysicalPath)\Bin\*.refresh">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="Project_[...]_References_RefreshFile" />
    </CreateItem>
    <!-- The contents of the *.refresh are read to [...]_References_ReferenceRelPath -->
    <ReadLinesFromFile Condition=" '%(Project_[...]_References_RefreshFile.Identity)' != '' " File="%(Project_[...]_References_RefreshFile.Identity)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="Project_[...]_References_ReferenceRelPath" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    <!-- Those contents are relative to [...]_AspNetPhysicalPath -->
    <CombinePath BasePath="$(Project_[...]_AspNetPhysicalPath)" Paths="@(Project_[...]_References_ReferenceRelPath)">
      <Output TaskParameter="CombinedPaths" ItemName="Project_[...]_References" />
    </CombinePath>
    <!-- This seems to be a no-op, since you cannot copy if it doesn't exist -->
    <Copy Condition="!Exists('%(Project_[...]_References.Identity)')" ContinueOnError="true" SourceFiles="@(Project_[...]_References->'%(FullPath)')" DestinationFolder="$(Project_[...]_AspNetPhysicalPath)\Bin\" />
    <!-- Edit: Snipped -->
    <!-- This will copy [...]_References to [...]_References_CopyLocalFiles and add references -->
    <ResolveAssemblyReference Condition="Exists('%(Project_[...]_References.Identity)')" Assemblies="@(Project_[...]_References->'%(FullPath)')" TargetFrameworkDirectories="$(Project_[...]__TargetFrameworkDirectories)" FullFrameworkFolders="$(Project_[...]__FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths)" SearchPaths="{RawFileName};{TargetFrameworkDirectory};{GAC}" FindDependencies="true" FindSatellites="true" FindSerializationAssemblies="true" FindRelatedFiles="true" TargetFrameworkMoniker=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5">
      <Output TaskParameter="CopyLocalFiles" ItemName="Project_[...]_References_CopyLocalFiles" />
    </ResolveAssemblyReference>
    <!-- [...]_References_CopyLocalFiles is copied to the bin directory -->
    <Copy Condition="(false) or ('$(AspNetConfiguration)' == 'Debug') or ('$(AspNetConfiguration)' == 'Release')" SourceFiles="@(Project_[...]_References_CopyLocalFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(Project_[...]_References_CopyLocalFiles->'$(Project_[...]_AspNetPhysicalPath)\Bin\%(DestinationSubDirectory)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
    <!-- Edit: Snipped -->
  </Target>
  <!-- Edit: Snipped -->
</Project>
```

I have not tried this on a machine which does not have VS installed, so it may not apply directly, but you should definitely be able to build with the generated `metaproj` file even without Visual Studio installed.

Comment: I will accept this as the answer, what I have found as I dig farther into the issue is that our solution file is corrupt/bad.  Other than the *.refresh files if you add the existing projects to your solution and reference then your solution file will have GUID references and you don't need the *.refresh files.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well; the problem was actually that our build configuration was neither Debug nor Release, so msbuild was actually skipping the compile (and thus the restore with *.refresh):

> Skipping because the "Dev" configuration is not supported for this web
>   project.  You can use the AspNetConfiguration property to override the
>   configuration used for building web projects, by adding
>   /p:AspNetConfiguration= to the command line. Currently web
>   projects only support Debug and Release configurations.